# The construction : "being"+adjective=noun

Tags: gerunds

Does the pattern below makes sense?

"being" + adjective  =  noun

Here are the examples that employ this pattern:

I am not afraid of being critical of any corporate division, including HR, when necessary.

Thanks to installing the antivirus software, we are not in danger of being blocked from vicious stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Both your examples are fully grammatical and idiomatic.

A clause containing a verb in the "-ing" form (a 'gerund') is indeed one kind of noun phrase. It's much more general than "being + adjective".

Some words and phrases accept such a clause as an argument (eg *afraid of*, *in danger of*, *like*, *encourage*); some don't (eg *want*, *disinclined*). I *think* that any phrase that introduces its complement with "of" will allow it - at least I can't think of any counter-examples.